# How to display an image inside Django Admin's detail view of a model?

Tags: python, django

I want to display an image inside a detail view of a model, when browsing through Django Admin. I have seen other posts about displaying images in the list view of all instances of a model in Django Admin. But I'm interested in seeing the image on the page where you can edit the data.
[image: What I have without the image.]

models.py

```py
class Label(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()
    fragment = models.ForeignKey('Fragment', models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    in_english = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fragment)
```

admin.py

```py
@admin.register(Label)
class LabelsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("label", "in_english", "validated", )
    
    # What I tried. This is not working even after adding 'image' to the fields. I get an error.
    # def image(self, obj):
    #     return format_html('<img src="{0}" />'.format(f"/static/fragments/{obj}.png"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you create a method like display_image.

```
def display_image(self, obj):
    # get image url 
    image_url = '<your_image_url>'
    if image_url is not None:
        return format_html('<img src="{}">', image_url)
    return None
```

Add 'display_image' in fields list

```
fields = ("label", "in_english", "validated", 'display_image')
```

then make this field as a readonly

```
readonly_fields = ['display_image']
```